# Is there any way to compile and run .java file from sdcard at run time in android

Tags: java, android, dex

I want to make an ide that is offline, I can write the java programs in textArea in UI and then save those files in sd-card, but the problem is that I am not able to execute it using this "Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);"
And many apps are doing this so I need the way to do this.

There are several .java files placed in a folder(test) in sd-card, is there any way that I can compile and run that java code from an app at run time.

Like converting .java files into a .dex file so that Android can read it.

I want to know how it can be done programmatically I have read several answers like
"[Is it possible to dynamically load a library at runtime from an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat)"
"[Creating a DEX file from Java source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348327/creating-a-dex-file-from-java-source-code)"

but nothing is working. I want some jar files or some method that can do this job for me.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Comment: I want to know how they are compiling and running the java codes offline?

Comment: I haven't looked, but I assume they're probably using the openjdk compiler to compile java to .class, and then the dx tool included with the android sdk to convert the .class files to dex

Comment: Can you tell me the open JDK compiler available over web that will suit my requirement.

Comment: Nope. I cannot.